# How do I earn Overwatch League tokens?

Tags: overwatch

I know I can buy them, but is there any other way?  I saw [this article](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/142583) which states you can earn it by watching Twitch streams, but it didn't say which streams or when they are.

Comment: We're between Overwatch League seasons at the moment, so you can't get OWL tokens from watching streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Buy them  - you already know it, but for the sake of completeness - [Shop Page](https://us.shop.battle.net/en-gb/product/overwatch-league-tokens)
2. Watch [Overwatch League](https://www.twitch.tv/overwatchleague) on Twitch. Also, some conditions need to be met (from [this support article](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/142823)):

> 1. Make sure you've set up and linked your accounts correctly.
> 2. Disable any ad blockers while watching.
> 3. Google Chrome has a power saving feature which will pause a broadcast if you mute the tab and navigate to a different tab—this will prevent you from earning tokens.
> 4. If watching on Twitch, make sure your Twitch profile in the upper-right corner says you're watching Overwatch League.
> 5. Your Blizzard account must be associated with one of the participating countries

3. Signing up to receive updates via email from Overwatch League website grants 100 one time. ([source](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Overwatch_League_Tokens))